# Why does browser not showing website changes html

Tags: html, browser

I am using html to create a page. But the problem i am facing is that, i changed the meta description and og description for a specific page statically but it is not showing while we checking the source code by using (ctrl+u). But while checking the code using inspect element (F12) i can saw the meta changes that i've done. I am facing this kind of issue first time. Can any one explain why this issue occurs. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: share your code here so we can clearify what wrong

Answer (score 0):

**Try disabling the cache and then reload** - it may be that the old version has been cached by your browser

On Chrome:

1. Open Developer Tools (CTRL+Shift+I)
2. Go to the network tab
3. Check the ‘disable cache’ checkbox
4. Reload

(See this: https://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-how-to-completely-disable-cache)

*Please do share your code though: we can help you more if we can have a look at it!*